# Deserializing redis's Value in Rust (FromRedisValue)

Tags: rust, redis, serde

I'm implementing a simple task queue using [redis](https://crates.io/crates/redis) in Rust, but am struggling to deserialize the returned values from redis into my custom types.

In total I thought of 3 approches:

1. Deserializing using [serde-redis](https://github.com/OneSignal/serde-redis)
2. Manually implementing the `FromRedisValue` trait
3. Serializing to String using [serde-json](https://github.com/serde-rs/json) > sending as string > then deserializing from string

The 3rd approach worked but feels artificial. I'd like to figure out either 1 or 2, both of which I'm failing at.

## Approach 1 - serde-redis

I have a simple Task definition:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, serde::Deserialize, serde::Serialize)]
pub struct Task {
    pub id: u32,
    pub desc: String,
}
```

which I'm trying to receive into a worker:

```
use serde_redis::RedisDeserialize;

pub fn execute_task(conn: &mut Connection) {
    let task: Task = redis::cmd("LPOP")
        .arg("task_q")
        .query::<Task>(conn)
        .unwrap()
        .deserialize()
        .unwrap();

    println!("... executing task {} ...", task.id);
}
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Task: FromRedisValue` is not satisfied
  --> src/bin/worker.rs:38:10
   |
38 |         .query::<Task>(conn)
   |          ^^^^^ the trait `FromRedisValue` is not implemented for `Task`

error[E0599]: no method named `deserialize` found for struct `Task` in the current scope
  --> src/bin/worker.rs:40:10
   |
40 |         .deserialize()
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Task`
```

So clearly I integrated the crate wrong, as it's not working. The documentation is super brief and the source code way over my head as a beginner - what could I be missing?

## Approach 2 - manually implementing FromRedisValue

My naive approach:

```
impl FromRedisValue for Task {
    fn from_redis_value(v: &Value) -> RedisResult<Self> {
        let t = Task {
            id: v.id,
            desc: v.desc,
        };
        RedisResult::Ok(t)
    }

    fn from_redis_values(items: &[Value]) -> RedisResult<Vec<Self>> {
        let tasks = items
            .into_iter()
            .map(|v| Task {
                id: v.id,
                desc: v.desc,
            })
            .collect();
        RedisResult::Ok(tasks)
    }
}
```

The errors I'm getting:

```
error[E0609]: no field `id` on type `&Value`
   --> src/redis_tut.rs:203:19
    |
203 |             id: v.id,
    |                   ^^

error[E0609]: no field `desc` on type `&Value`
   --> src/redis_tut.rs:204:21
    |
204 |             desc: v.desc,
    |                     ^^^^

// ...the same for the vector implementation
```

So clearly redis's Value doesn't have / know of the fields I want for Task. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis doesn't define structured serialization formats. It mostly store strings and integers. So you have to choose or define your format for your struct.

A popular one is JSON, as you noticed, but if you just want to (de)serialize simple pairs of (id, description), it's not very readable nor convenient.

In such a case, you can define your own format, for example the id and the description with a dash in between:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Task {
    pub id: u32,
    pub desc: String,
}
// assume a task is defined as "<id>-<desc>"
impl FromRedisValue for Task {
    fn from_redis_value(v: &Value) -> RedisResult<Self> {
        let v: String = from_redis_value(v)?;
        if let Some((id, desc)) = v.split_once('-') {
            if let Ok(id) = id.parse() {
                Ok(Task {
                    id,
                    desc: desc.to_string(),
                })
            } else {
                Err((ErrorKind::TypeError, "bad first token").into())
            }
        } else {
            Err((ErrorKind::TypeError, "missing dash").into())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so in this solution when I'm sending the struct into redis I would write a "to_str()" method that converts into <id>-<desc>, correct? This, vs what I have right now which is json_serde::to_str() and then json_serde::from_str() the other end?

Comment: Yes. If it's the natural way to describe a task, you can also leverage the `Display` trait, meaning you would use `to_string` which is automatically available when you implement the trait.

Answer (score 2):

I actually wrote a crate for this kind of Problem, it provides Derive Macros that implements the redis::FromRedisValue and redis::ToRedisArgs traits from mitsuhiko / redis-rs for any struct in which every field's type also implements ToRedisArgs. Check it out [redis-redive](https://github.com/michaelvanstraten/redis-derive).

Comment: I need both, so your solution is a good fit for me. Are you planing to maintain it or push it upstream into redis-rs?

Comment: Yes, I am actually working on a big release. But I am not sure if it fits into the redis-rs crate.

Comment: The problem is that, to fully utilize the Redis type system, I would need to execute more than one command. For example, a Struct that has a field of type vec or slice should not include that field in the Redis hash. My approach would be to write the data of the field into a separate key of type list. To implement this, ToRedisArgs/FromRedisValue is too inflexible.